# Prove that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2013 x)}{x(\cos x+\cosh x)}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Prove that
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2013 x)}{x(\cos x+\cosh x)}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: 1. The integrand is even.  2. Use Parseval's Theorem.

Comment: @rlgordonma: good point. I'll check this way! Thanks!

Comment: @rlgordonma Please enlighten me: I only know Parseval for, say, $2\pi$ periodic functions and their integral over $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: @julien: it is also applied to functions defined on $L^2(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: @rlgordonma Do you have a reference? The only analogue of Parseval I know of on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is Plancherel.

Comment: @julien: here's an example of using Parseval in evaluating a tough integral: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288049/how-to-integrate-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-cosh-x-cos-x-cdot-frac/288095#288095

Comment: And yes, it is more properly called Plancherel's Theorem.  But many people (like my Optics colleagues) just call it Parseval's theorem all the same.

Comment: @rlgordonma Thank you for the link. Ah! Plancherel, this I know. I see, Wikipedia confirms that it is often called Parseval in other domains of science and engineering fields.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Nice question, as always. +1

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: It's not a contest question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because the integrand is even, contour integration yields
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(mx)}{x(\cos(x)+\cosh(x))}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(mx)}{x(\cos(x)+\cosh(x))}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty-i}^{\infty-i}\frac{\sin(mx)}{x(\cos(x)+\cosh(x))}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{4i}\int_{\gamma^+}\frac{e^{imz}}{z(\cos(z)+\cosh(z))}\mathrm{d}z
-\frac1{4i}\int_{\gamma^-}\frac{e^{-imz}}{z(\cos(z)+\cosh(z))}\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac{2\pi i}{4i}\frac12
+2\frac{2\pi i}{4i}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\mathrm{sech}\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right)}{\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi}\frac{\cos\left(m\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right)}{\exp\left(m\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right)}\\
&=\frac\pi4+\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\mathrm{sech}\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right)}{\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi}\frac{\cos\left(m\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right)}{\exp\left(m\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right)}\\
&=\frac\pi4\qquad\text{for odd $m$}
\end{align}
$$
where $\gamma^+$ goes from $-R-i$ to $+R-i$ then circles counterclockwise back in the upper half plane along $|z+i|=R$ and $\gamma^+$ goes from $-R-i$ to $+R-i$ then circles clockwise back in the lower half plane along $|z+i|=R$.

The residue of $f(z)=\dfrac{e^{imz}}{z(\cos(z)+\cosh(z))}$ at $z=0$ is $\frac12$.

Let $\alpha=\frac{1+i}{2}$. As noted in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/296214), $f$ has singularities at $\pm(2k+1)\pi\alpha$ and $\pm(2k+1)\pi\overline{\alpha}$.

The sum of the residues in the upper half plane at $(2k+1)\pi\alpha$ and $-(2k+1)\pi\overline{\alpha}$ is the same as the sum of the residues in the lower half plane at $(2k+1)\pi\overline{\alpha}$ and $-(2k+1)\pi\alpha$. Both are equal to
$$
(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\mathrm{sech}\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right)}{\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi}\frac{\cos\left(m\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right)}{\exp\left(m\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\right)}
$$
Note that for odd $m$, these are all $0$; $x=m\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\equiv\frac\pi2\pmod{\pi}\Rightarrow\cos(x)=0$. This is not so for even $m$. Thus,
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(2013x)}{x(\cos(x)+\cosh(x))}\mathrm{d}x=\frac\pi4
$$

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the complex analysis makes miracles. Very nice. (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: I first looked to see if the function was even so that I could extend the domain of integration to $(-\infty,+\infty)$ in order to use contour integration.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: Not to be picky, but my name is Rob :-) thanks for the bounty, arrrgh!

Comment: OK! Welcome. :-)

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: I am trying this integral in Mathematica, and it is taking a *long* time.

Comment: yeah. I tried to compute it with Mathematica, but I got no result.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: I just noticed a mistake which I am fixing.

Comment: take your time. There is no hurry here.

Comment: @robjohn Your work is a masterpiece! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Consider a general case:

$$I(m)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(m x)}{x(\cos x+\cosh x)}dx$$ where $m$ is a positive integer.

At first, let's try with m=1

$$I(1)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x(\cos x+\cosh x)}dx$$ As a first step we note that

$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x+\cosh x}=-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^ke^{-xk}\sin(xk)$$ This relationship can be derived from the following geometric series sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^ke^{-xk}e^{ixk}=-\frac{e^{-x}e^{ix}}{1+e^{-x}e^{ix}}$$ Imaginary part of this gives the relationship above. Thus, the integral:

$$I(1)=-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xk}\sin(xk)\frac{dx}{x}$$ But

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xk}\sin(xk)\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ This result follows from the well known integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xa}\sin(xk)dx=\frac{k}{a^2+k^2}$$ if we integrate the last with respect to $a$ from $a=k$ to $a=\infty$.  We get:

$$I(1)=-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}$$ The sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}=1-1+1-1+...=\frac{1}{2}$$  was already known in the times of Leibniz.

Finally:

$$I(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ But even in the next case of $m=2$ i have no clue, how to evaluate the integral. Numerical calculations suggest that the result holds for every $m$ including $m=2013$

Comment: +1 for the $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x) + \cosh(x)}$ expansion. Nice!

Comment: How do you prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}=\frac12$ although the partial sum $s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}=(1-(-1)^n)/2$ does not converge?

Comment: @Mercy $\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+...$

Comment: @MartinGales Yes, that's true only for $|x|<1$.

Comment: @Mercy $\lim_{x\to1-0}(1-x+x^2-x^3+...)=\lim_{x\to1-0}\frac{1}{1+x}=\frac{1}{2}$. I am not saying that the sum converges to $\frac{1}{2}$. I am saying that the sum is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @MartinGales I still don't see why the sum should be $1/2$. Are you using some "advanced calculus" to prove it? All I can see is that $s_{2n}=0$ and $s_{2n+1}=1$, and with my current knowledge of calculus, the latter tells me that this sum does not exist.

Comment: @MartinGales: an infinite alternating sum like that is a red flag that something has gone wrong in a problem like this.  Have another look, especially why you can only work the case $m=1$.  The result is clearly independent of $m$ - that's how all of these problems with the year stuck in as a parameter work.

Comment: @Mercy Look at Cesàro summation on Wikipedia.

Comment: @rlgordonma How do you show that the integral is independent of $m$?

Comment: @MartinGales I think you are mixing things up, it is clear that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}$ does not converge, and I'm surprised you still believe it does. In fact, a necessary condition for the convergence of a series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is that $a_k \to 0$ which obviously is not satisfied.

Comment: @MartinGales: it is a lot harder to prove than I thought, but I do believe it.  Sort of like a religion at this point until I solve the problem, or see it solve to my satisfaction.  BTW I got the same sum representation as you.  Although your result is right, you do need to argue away from that horrendous alternating sum.

Comment: @rlgordonma I(0)=0& I(-x)=-I(x). So, the integral is not as independent of parameter as hoped.

Comment: @MartinGales I'm affraid I have to agree with Mercy, I don't see why the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}$ should be convergent since the limit $\lim_{k \to \infty}(-1)^{k-1}$ is not zero.

Comment: @Mercy I repeat what I have said above: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}$ **does not converge to** $\frac{1}{2}$, **it is exactly equal to** $\frac{1}{2}$. Like 1+1 does not converge to 2, it is equal to 2.

Comment: Yup the limit as k goes to infinity of (-1)^(k-1) absolutely does no convege. It oscillates between 1 and -1.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says it, the sum, doesn't converge also

Comment: [Grandi series](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi's_series) explains the summation somewhat

Comment: @MartinGales: for a series to converge, [its terms must tend to $0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test). Cesàro summation is a method to evaluate series which do not converge. From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation): "The significance of Cesàro summation is that a series which **does not converge** may still have a well-defined Cesàro sum."

Comment: @MartinGales: The integral is not independent of $m$. If $m$ is odd, the integral is $\frac\pi4$. If $m$ is even, this is not so.

Comment: @robjohn I agree with your last comment.

Answer (score 9):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{2013 x}\,\dd x
     \over x\bracks{\cos\pars{x} + \cosh\pars{ x}}}={\pi \over 4}:\ {\large ?}}$

> Note that
>   \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\cos\pars{x} + \cosh\pars{x}}
> =\cos\pars{x} + \cos\pars{x\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\cos\pars{{x + x\ic \over 2} + {x - x\ic \over 2}}
> +\cos\pars{{x + x\ic \over 2} - {x - x\ic \over 2}}
> =2\cos\pars{x + x\ic \over 2}\cos\pars{x - x\ic \over 2}
> \\[3mm]&=2\cos\pars{\mu x}\cos\pars{\mu^{*}x}
> \qquad\mbox{where}\qquad\mu\equiv{1 + \ic \over 2} = \expo{\pi\ic/4}
> \end{align}

Then,
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{m x}\,\dd x
\over x\bracks{\cos\pars{x} + \cosh\pars{ x}}}}
={1 \over 4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{mx} \over x\cos\pars{\mu x}\cos\pars{\mu^{*}x}}\,\dd x\end{align}
With the identity
$\ds{{\sin\pars{\xi} \over \xi} = \int_{0}^{1}\cos\pars{k\xi}\,\dd k
     =\Re\int_{0}^{1}\expo{\ic\verts{k}\xi}\,\dd k}$ we'll have:
$$
\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{m x}\,\dd x
\over x\bracks{\cos\pars{x} + \cosh\pars{ x}}}}
={1 \over 4}\,m\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}\color{#00f}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{\ic\verts{mk}x}\,\dd x \over \cos\pars{\mu x}\cos\pars{\mu^{*}x}}}\,\dd k
\tag{1}
$$

> Zeros of $\ds{\cos\pars{\mu x}}$ are given by
>   $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\ n \in {\mathbb Z}~}}$:
>   $$
> x_{n} = \pars{n + \half}\,{\pi \over \mu}
> =\pars{2n + 1}\,\pars{1 - \ic}\,{\pi \over 2}\,,\qquad
> \Im\pars{x_{n}} > 0\quad\mbox{if}\quad n=-1,-2,-3,\ldots
> $$
>   Similarly, zeros of $\ds{\cos\pars{\mu^{*}x}}$ are given by $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\ n \in {\mathbb Z}~}}$:
>   $$
> x_{n}^{*} = \pars{n + \half}\,{\pi \over \mu^{*}}
> =\pars{2n + 1}\,\pars{1 + \ic}\,{\pi \over 2}\,,\qquad
> \Im\pars{x_{n}^{*}} > 0\quad\mbox{if}\quad n=0,1,2,\ldots
> $$
>   $\large\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
> \mbox{Note that}\quad \ds{x_{-n - 1} = -x_{n}}\\ \hline\end{array}$.

Then,
\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{\ic\verts{mk}x}\,\dd x \over \cos\pars{\mu x}\cos\pars{\mu^{*}x}}}
\\[3mm]&=2\pi\ic\bracks{%
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{-1}
{\expo{\ic\verts{mk}x_{n}} \over -\mu\sin\pars{\mu x_{n}}\cos\pars{\mu^{*}x_{n}}}
+
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\expo{\ic\verts{mk}x_{n}*}\over
\cos\pars{\mu x_{n}^{*}}\pars{-\mu*}\sin\pars{\mu^{*}x_{n}^{*}}}}
\\[3mm]&=2\pi\ic\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{\expo{-\ic\verts{mk}x_{n}} \over \mu\sin\pars{\mu x_{n}}\cos\pars{\mu^{*}x_{n}}}
-
{\expo{\ic\verts{mk}x_{n}*}\over
\mu^{*}\sin\pars{\mu^{*}x_{n}^{*}}\cos\pars{\mu x_{n}^{*}}}}
\\[3mm]&=-4\pi\,\Im
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\mu^{*} \over \verts{\mu}^{2}}\,
{\expo{-\ic\verts{mk}x_{n}} \over \sin\pars{\mu x_{n}}\cos\pars{\mu^{*}x_{n}}}
\\[3mm]&=-4\pi\,\Im
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{1 - \ic}/2 \over 1/2}\,
{\expo{-\ic\verts{mk}x_{n}}\over
\sin\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi/2}\cos\pars{\ic\bracks{2n + 1}\pi/2}}
\end{align}

> $$\color{#00f}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> {\expo{\ic\verts{mk}x}\,\dd x \over \cos\pars{\mu x}\cos\pars{\mu^{*}x}}}
> =-4\pi\,\Im
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \cosh\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi/2}}\,
> \pars{1 - \ic}\expo{-\ic\verts{mk}x_{n}}
> $$

We replace this result in expression $\pars{1}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{m x}\,\dd x
\over x\bracks{\cos\pars{x} + \cosh\pars{ x}}}}
=-\pi\,m\,\Im
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \cosh\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi/2}}\,
\pars{1 - \ic}\int_{0}^{1}\expo{-\ic\verts{m}x_{n}k}\,\dd k
\\[3mm]&=-\pi\,m\,\Im
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \cosh\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi/2}}\,
\pars{1 - \ic}\,{\expo{-\ic\verts{m}x_{n}} - 1 \over -\ic\verts{m}x_{n}}
\\[3mm]&=-\pi \sgn\pars{m}\Im
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \cosh\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi/2}}\,
\,\ic\,{\expo{-\ic\verts{m}\pars{2n + 1}\pi/2}
\expo{-\verts{m}\pars{2n + 1}\pi/2} - 1 \over \pars{2n + 1}\pi/2}
\\[3mm]&=-2\sgn\pars{m}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n}\over
\pars{2n + 1}\cosh\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi/2}}\times
\\[3mm]&
\phantom{=-2\sgn\pars{m}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}}
\bracks{\cos\pars{\verts{m}\pars{2n + 1}\,{\pi \over 2}}
\expo{-\verts{m}\pars{2n + 1}\pi/2} - 1}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $$
> 2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n}\over
> \pars{2n + 1}\cosh\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi/2}} = {\pi \over 4}
> $$

\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{m x}\,\dd x
\over x\bracks{\cos\pars{x} + \cosh\pars{ x}}}}=
\\[3mm]&\color{#c00000}{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
{\pi \over 4}\,\sgn\pars{m} & \mbox{if} & m\ \mbox{is odd}
\\[3mm]\sgn\pars{m}\braces{%
{\pi \over 4}
-2\pars{-1}^{\verts{m}/2}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,
{\expo{-\verts{m}\pars{2n + 1}\pi/2}\over
\pars{2n + 1}\cosh\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi/2}}}
 & \mbox{if} & m\ \mbox{is even}
\end{array}\right.}
\end{align}