# How to show $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^3 x}{\cosh x\>+\>\cos x}\frac{dx}x=\frac{\pi}{8}$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to evaluate the integral below$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^3 x}{\cosh x+\cos x}\frac{dx}x $$
which I found to be $\frac \pi8$ numerically. I was able to evaluate a similarly looking, yet simpler, integral
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{\cosh x+\cos x}\frac{dx}x =\frac\pi4$$
by writing the integrand in the Frullani format and apply the theorem. However, it does not work in this case and I am not sure if they are related. Any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since
$$
\frac{\sin(x)}{\cosh(x)+\cos(x)}=2\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^{n-1}e^{-nx}\sin(nx
)$$
(shown [here](https://ysharificalc.wordpress.com/2020/02/03/interesting-integrals-8/)), we can combine the above with $\sin^2(x)\sin(nx) = \frac14 \left[2 \sin(n x) + \sin((2  - n) x) - \sin((2 + n) x)\right]$ and [$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\frac{\sin{(bx)}}{x}\mathrm{d}x = \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3439469/695196) to get
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{x}\left[2 \sin(n x) + \sin((2  - n) x) - \sin((2 + n) x)\right] \, \mathrm{d}x\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^{n-1} \left[\frac\pi2 + \arctan\left(\frac{2-n}{n} \right) - \arctan\left(\frac{2+n}{n} \right)\right]\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^{n-1}  \left[\arctan(n+1) - \arctan(n-1)\right]\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left[-\arctan(0) + \arctan(1) \right]\\
 & = \frac{\pi}{8}
\end{align*}
as desired.

---

Note that to re-write the arctangent expressions from equations $2\to 3$ we combine [$\arctan(\alpha) - \arctan(\beta) = \arctan\left(\frac{\alpha - \beta}{1 + \alpha\beta} \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/326538/695196) and [$\arctan(x) + \arctan\left( \frac1x\right)= \frac\pi2,\ x>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/720529/695196). Thus
\begin{align*}
\frac\pi2 + \arctan\left(\frac{2-n}{n} \right) - \arctan\left(\frac{2+n}{n} \right) &=\frac\pi2 + \arctan\left(\frac{-n^2}{2}\right) \\
&\overset{\color{blue}{n^2/2 >0}}{=}  \arctan\left(\frac{2}{n^2}\right) \\
&=\arctan(n+1) - \arctan(n-1)
\end{align*}
also exploiting the fact that $\arctan(x)$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

It was shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/314228) that if $n$ is a nonnegative integer, then $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\left((2n+1)x \right)}{\cosh (x) + \cos (x)} \, \, \frac{\mathrm dx}{x} = \frac{\pi}{4}. $$

Therefore, $$\begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{3}(x)}{\cosh (x) + \cos (x)} \, \frac{\mathrm dx}{x} &= \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{3 \sin (x)- \sin(3x)}{\cosh (x) + \cos (x)} \, \frac{\mathrm dx}{x} \\ & = \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{3 \pi}{4}- \frac{\pi}{4} \right) \\ & = \frac{\pi}{8}. \end{align}$$

In general, if $m$ is a nonnegative integer, then $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2m+1}(x)}{\cosh (x) + \cos (x)} \, \frac{\mathrm dx}{x} &\overset{(1)}{=} \frac{1}{2^{2m}} \sum_{k=0}^{m} (-1)^{m-k} \binom{2m+1}{k} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin \left((2m+1-2k)x \right)}{\cosh(x) + \cos (x)}\frac{\mathrm dx}{x} \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2^{2m+2}}\sum_{k=0}^{m} (-1)^{m-k} \binom{2m+1}{k}. \end{align}$$

$(1)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae

Answer (score 0):

We know that:
$$2\sin^2(x) = 1-\cos(2x)$$
Therefore, we could re-write your integral as:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^3(x)}{\cosh(x)+\cos(x)} \frac{dx}{x} =\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)-\sin(x)\cos(2x)}{\cosh(x)+\cos(x)} \frac{dx}{x}$$

But we find that:
$$\sin(3x) = \sin(x+2x) = \sin(x)\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\cos(x)$$
$$\sin(x) = \sin(2x-x) = \sin(2x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\cos(2x)$$
from which it follows that $2\sin(x)\cos(2x) = \sin(3x)-\sin(x)$. So:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^3(x)}{\cosh(x)+\cos(x)} \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{\pi}{8} - \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(3x)-\sin(x)}{\cosh(x)+\cos(x)} \frac{dx}{x}$$

and we find that the second term vanishes by Frullani's Theorem so the result now follows.

**Edit**

So, that last term does not vanish by Frullani's Theorem because it is not of Frullani type, I mistakenly thought that it was. However, you could likely show that it vanishes by using the residue theorem.

Comment: Could you spell out why the last term is a Frullani integral?