# Prove or disprove $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{\cos x+\cosh x}=\frac{1512835691 \pi}{1983703776}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, closed-form

In this question, [Evaluating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {dx}{\cos x + \cosh x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295989/evaluating-the-integral-int-infty-infty-frac-dx-cos-x-cosh-x) , robjohn evaluates the integral to a nice summation with an approximate value. When plugged into W|A, it gives a possible closed form as $\dfrac{1512835691 \pi}{1983703776}$, correct to at least 20 decimal digits. When subtracting the two in W|A, it gives a nice result of $0$. ([1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2pi%28sum%20%28n%3D0%20to%20infinity%29%20%28-1%29%5En%20sech%28n*pi%2Bpi%2F2%29%29)) Can we prove that it equals the conjectured closed form?

Comment: Note that you have approximated a $20$ digit number with the ratio of two $10$ digit numbers. Standard approximation theorems say that this is not unusual at all.

Comment: For example, with 40 digit numerator and denominator, we can get $$\frac{2613603931557187475711267138492580362408} {3427084658857667283712884858756158507063} \,\pi$$ which is correct to $80$ places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not the correct value. The value of the integral with $70$ digits precision is
$$\underline{2.395878633914562092}453189586490058501300873812447750729519628041973530$$

And the conjectured expression is
$$\underline{2.395878633914562092}589756143323601049570678313084832875204827253396682$$

The two values are not equal.

Comment: It's still an amazing coincidence, isn't it? Just so I know how impressed I should be, what are the odds that a random real number cn be approximated to 20 digit accuracy by the ratio of two 10-digit numbers?

Comment: @bof these are not random real numbers. WolframAlpha has algorithms and databases to get possible closed-form expressions. Ten or twenty digits of consistency is nothing. The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Symbolic_Calculator) is much better for conjecturing closed-form expressions.

Comment: @bof Interesting question! I'm not an expert on this, but I suppose Dirichlet's approximation theorem tells us that it's common to get $2N$ digits from an $N$-digit denominator.

Comment: (+1) However, your number appears to be $70$ digits instead of $80$

Answer (score 2):

Another expression for it, BTW, is 
$$ 4 \pi \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sigma_0(2j+1) (-1)^j \exp(-(j+1/2)\pi) $$
where $\sigma_0$ is the [number of divisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) function.
If your number is $\pi x$, then the continued fraction of $x$ starts

$$[0; 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 12, 2, 4, 3, 104, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 21, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 17, 1, 6, 5, 2, 2, 59, 1, 8, 3, 42, 15, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 12, 2, 3, 1, 2, 8, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 18, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 20, 5, 10]$$

(i.e. $0 + 1/(1 + 1/(3+1/(4+1/\ldots)))$), which shows no sign of terminating; there's no reason to think it is rational, nor is it unusually well approximated by rationals.