# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{\cosh ax+\cos x}\frac{x}{x^2-\pi^2}dx=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)-\frac{1}{a}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Please help me prove the following identity: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{\cosh ax+\cos x}\frac{x}{x^2-\pi^2}dx=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)-\frac{1}{a}\quad a>0$$
This integral is from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's tables.

Comment: I managed to reduce it down to $$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)e^{-anx}}{x^2-\pi^2}\,dx\right)$$ but I can't evaluate the integral in terms of $n$ and $a$ and I am not sure if what I have reached is correct.

Comment: Maybe Plancherels Theorem can help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> **Lemma.** For $a>0$ and $x\in\Bbb{R}$,
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty2(-1)^{n-1}\sin(nx)e^{-anx}=\frac{\sin x}{\cosh(ax)+\cos x}\tag {1}
> $$

*Proof.* Indeed,
$$\eqalign{
\sum_{n=1}^\infty2(-1)^{n-1}\sin(nx)e^{-anx}&=
-2\Im\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n e^{(i-a)nx}\right)\cr
&=2\Im\left(\frac{e^{(i-a)x}}{1+e^{(i-a)x}}\right)\cr
&=\frac{\sin x}{\cosh(ax)+\cos x}.\qquad\square
}$$

Now, let
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{\cosh(ax)+\cos x}\cdot\frac{x}{x^2-\pi^2}\,dx.$$
Then 
$$\eqalign{
I(a)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2(-1)^{n-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{x^2-\pi^2}\sin(nx)e^{-anx}dx\cr
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2(-1)^{n-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{t}{t^2-n^2\pi^2}\sin t e^{-at}dt\cr
&=\int_0^\infty\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2t(-1)^{n-1}}{t^2-n^2\pi^2}\right)\sin t e^{-at}dt\cr
&\buildrel{(*)}\over{=}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{\sin t}\right)\sin t e^{-at}dt\cr
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin t}{t} e^{-at}dt-\int_0^\infty e^{-at}dt\cr
&=\arctan\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{a}
}
$$
as desired.

For more information on the partial fraction decomposition $(*)$ of the $\csc$ function, one may consult [Alfors' Book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Complex_analysis.html?id=2MRuus-5GGoC) Chapter 5. pp.185--188. $\qquad\square$

Comment: Thanks! It's very nice and easy :)

Comment: $\displaystyle\ldots\mbox{and}\ a > 0$.